# Python method with multiple response.out.write statements

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, httpresponse, google-app-engine-python

Could someone please confirm for me whether the following should work in Python? Someone calls the server and the response can be return in a number of ways. Instead of using nested "ifs" I was hoping to do as follows:

```
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        data = fromLocationOne()
        if data is not None:
            return self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
        data = fromLocationTwo()
        if data is not None:
            return self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
            data = fromLocationThree()
        if data is not None:
            return self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: You have the `data = fromLocationThree()` indented too far, but other than that I assume this would work - have you actually tried it?  Note that you could vastly simplify this to `data = fromLocationOne() or fromLocationTwo() or fromLocationThree()` (assuming that these functions have no possible return value other than None which is false, such as an empty list or dict).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work for simplicity you can replace `if data is not None:` by `if data:`

If it was me I would write it as following

```
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    functions = [fromLocationOne, fromLocationTwo, fromLocationThree]
    for f in functions:
      data = f()
      if data:
        return self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
```